# What's the formula for producing these series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, exponentiation

I have a function which produces a series from an integer.  I currently do this iteratively.

```
f(0) =           []
f(1) =          [0]
f(2) =       [0, 0]
f(3) =       [0, 1]
f(4) =    [0, 0, 1]
f(5) =    [0, 1, 1]
f(6) =    [0, 0, 2]
f(7) =    [0, 1, 2]
f(8) = [0, 0, 1, 2]
```

There is another pattern here.

```
          []                             = 0
         [0]                        2**0 = 1 
      [0, 0]                 2**0 + 2**0 = 2
      [0, 1]                 2**0 + 2**1 = 3
   [0, 0, 1]          2**0 + 2**0 + 2**1 = 4
   [0, 1, 1]          2**0 + 2**1 + 2**1 = 5
   [0, 0, 2]          2**0 + 2**0 + 2**2 = 6
   [0, 1, 2]          2**0 + 2**1 + 2**2 = 7
[0, 0, 1, 2]   2**0 + 2**0 + 2**1 + 2**2 = 8
```

(Where double asterisk means 'raised to the power.)

Is there way to get from the argument, straight to the series, without working out all of the previous series?

---

Update, thanks for the interest.

Here's some Javascript code which generates the sequences, where `weight` is the sequence:

```
var numbers = [];

for (var count = 0; count < 20; count++) {
  for (var i = numbers.length; i > 0; i--) {
    if (count % (2**i) === 0) {
      numbers[i] = numbers[i - 1];
    }
  }
  numbers[0] = count;

  var weights = [];
  for (var j = 1; j < numbers.length; j++) {
    // note the differences below are all exact powers of 2
    weights[j] = Math.log2(numbers[j - 1] - numbers[j]);
  }
  if (numbers.length > 0) {
    weights[0] = 0;
  }

  console.log(`count ${count} numbers ${numbers} weight ${weights}`);
}
```

and the output:

```
count 0 numbers             0 weight          
count 1 numbers             1 weight         0
count 2 numbers           2,1 weight       0,0
count 3 numbers           3,1 weight       0,1
count 4 numbers         4,3,1 weight     0,0,1
count 5 numbers         5,3,1 weight     0,1,1
count 6 numbers         6,5,1 weight     0,0,2
count 7 numbers         7,5,1 weight     0,1,2
count 8 numbers       8,7,5,1 weight   0,0,1,2
count 9 numbers       9,7,5,1 weight   0,1,1,2
count 10 numbers     10,9,5,1 weight   0,0,2,2
count 11 numbers     11,9,5,1 weight   0,1,2,2
count 12 numbers    12,11,9,1 weight   0,0,1,3
count 13 numbers    13,11,9,1 weight   0,1,1,3
count 14 numbers    14,13,9,1 weight   0,0,2,3
count 15 numbers    15,13,9,1 weight   0,1,2,3
count 16 numbers 16,15,13,9,1 weight 0,0,1,2,3
count 17 numbers 17,15,13,9,1 weight 0,1,1,2,3
count 18 numbers 18,17,13,9,1 weight 0,0,2,2,3
count 19 numbers 19,17,13,9,1 weight 0,1,2,2,3
```

There seems to be an emergent restriction that the values in the Nth place of the series can only take values between 0 and N.

Comment: The pattern looks like: if there are no pairs of repeated digits add a zero to the left, if there are double digits increment the right most digit and set the left of the pair to zero. Am I right in thinking then that  $f(9)=[0,1,1,2],f(10)=[0,0,2,2]$? I can't see what to then do for f(11) because there are two pairs of repeated digits, it could be $[0,0,0,3]$ or $[0,1,2,2]$, I wouldn't know how to deal with a triple digit, so I guess it would be $[0,1,2,2]$.

Comment: Following that rule through large numbers seem to end in long strings of [...,0,3,0,3,0,3,0,3] etc.

Comment: @BenedictWilliamJohnIrwin Thanks for your interest, I've posted an update.

Comment: @Winther Yes, it is well defined.  I've posted a javascript function which generates the series in an update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have code in PARI/GP which is easy to translate:

```
{f(n) = if( n<=0, [], my(m = exponent(n)); 
        vector(m+1, j, my(i = j-2); if(i<0, 0, n\(2^i)%2 + i)))};
```

Here $\ \texttt{exponent(n) = floor(Log(2,n)).} \ $ Equvalent Mathematica code:

```
f[n_] := If[ n<=0, {}, With[{m = IntegerLength[n, 2] - 1},
         Table[ If[ i<0, 0, Mod[Quotient[n, 2^i], 2] + i], {i, -1, m-1}]]];
```

Comment: Thanks for a great answer.  How did you work it out?

Comment: I observed the pattern of the first digit (always 0), the 2nd digit (alternating 0,1), and so on. Then I wrote the code to implement those patterns.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a translation of @Somos' answer.

```
function f(n) {
  if (n <= 0) return [];
  const m = Math.log2(n);
  for (var j = 0, ret = []; j <= m; j++) {
    var i = j - 1;
    if (i < 0) {
      ret[j] = 0;
    } else {
      ret[j] = Math.floor((n / 2**i) % 2 + i);
    }
  }
  return ret;
}
for (var n = 0; n < 20; n++) {
  console.log(`n ${n}, series ${f(n)}`);
}
```

It outputs:

```
n 0, series 
n 1, series 0
n 2, series 0,0
n 3, series 0,1
n 4, series 0,0,1
n 5, series 0,1,1
n 6, series 0,0,2
n 7, series 0,1,2
n 8, series 0,0,1,2
n 9, series 0,1,1,2
n 10, series 0,0,2,2
n 11, series 0,1,2,2
n 12, series 0,0,1,3
n 13, series 0,1,1,3
n 14, series 0,0,2,3
n 15, series 0,1,2,3
n 16, series 0,0,1,2,3
n 17, series 0,1,1,2,3
n 18, series 0,0,2,2,3
n 19, series 0,1,2,2,3
```